# Why FQL query to list fb offers from a given location is not giving any results?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Please help me with FQL query not showing any results even though valid results are available at my location.

This is the query that i am using :
**SELECT id, title, owner_id, image_url, created_time, expiration_time, terms, claim_limit, coupon_type, redemption_link, redemption_code FROM offer WHERE owner_id IN (SELECT parent_page FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id,name FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, '-36.849423','174.755888') < 50000))**

Actually there are many valid offers available at my location. Please someone help me find a solution as I am stuck with this issue for days..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is old, so you have probably figured it out.

This query works for me in the API explorer:

```
SELECT id, title, owner_id, image_url, created_time, expiration_time, terms, claim_limit, coupon_type, redemption_link, redemption_code FROM offer WHERE owner_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, '-36.849423','174.755888') < 50000)
```